# Write data frame to Elastic Search with @timestamp

Tags: r, elasticsearch, ropensci

I am exploring the `elastic` R package to write a data frame to ElasticSearch.
I am using `docs_bulk` function.

One of the columns in my dataframe is **@timestamp** which is in `POSIXct` format.
But the field is getting saved in Elastic Search as string.
Any idea on how can I get the column saved in time format.

I also tried by manually created the index mapping with proper data type definition  but it didn't work.

Please suggest.

**Version:**

R: 3.3.1

Elastic Search - 2.4.1

OS - Redhat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elastic` doesn't try to capture data types from your input data.frame or list to `docs_bulk()` - We could think about trying to do that, but I imagine R data types wouldn't map exactly to Elasticsearch types - might play around with trying to map data types. Here's how I'd do it:

```
library('elastic')
connect()
```

Dummy data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = as.POSIXct(seq(from = as.Date("2016-10-01"), 
                        to = as.Date("2016-10-31"), by = 'day')),
  num = 1:31
)
```

Create a mapping, either as a list or JSON string

```
mapping <- list(
  world = list(properties = list(
    date = list(
      type = "date",
      format = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"
    ),
    num = list(type = "long")
)))
```

Make the index

```
index_create(index = "hello")
```

Create the mapping in the index

```
mapping_create(index = "hello", type = "world", body = mapping)
```

Get the mapping

```
mapping_get("hello")
#> $hello
#> $hello$mappings
#> $hello$mappings$world
#> $hello$mappings$world$properties
#> $hello$mappings$world$properties$date
#> $hello$mappings$world$properties$date$type
#> [1] "date"
#> 
#> $hello$mappings$world$properties$date$format
#> [1] "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"
#> 
#> 
#> $hello$mappings$world$properties$num
#> $hello$mappings$world$properties$num$type
#> [1] "long"
```

Bulk load data.frame

```
docs_bulk(df, index = "hello", type = "world")
```

Search on the index

```
Search("hello")
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. In the format, the month has to be MM